# How to call multiple FormView.Inserts from 1 button click

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

vb.net, .NET 4.0, sql server 2008 backend.
I have a webpage which contains 3 formviews, each within their own Panel. As the user traverses the page, depending on which step they're on, a certain formview will be visible. After the process is complete, the user will click the Submit button and The button onclick event calls each FormView.Insert statement. Each Formview inserts into a separate table. The issue is that if the last FormView.Insert throws an exception, the first 2 Inserts have already been executed successfully.

My question is, and I hope this isn't too vague but...What is my best option at this stage?
1. Create a single Stored Procedure to handle each Insert in order to handle if one of the Inserts throw an error?

Thank you.

Comment: I would have function that checks that all the forms are valid. If that passes then I would run the function that runs the insert. It depends of what kind of errors are you are encountering.

Comment: That sounds about right...I've been adding various validations to the form all day. There's approx 100 fields between the 3 FVs.  For now, I'm going to depend on the validation controls to ensure that data is correct. In time, I will probably create 1 stored proc that will insert into the 3 different tables.